# Lucene highlighting: highlight a token part

Tags: java, lucene

Good day.

The main question is the following: Am I understood correctly that Lucene can only highlight only a complete token from token stream?

In fact, I stuck in the following situation:

1. there is an document with keeps some identifier field, let it be 'IMEI' (15-digits number).
   'IMEI' doesn't need to be splatted to separate tokens, so I use KeywordAnalyser while indexing.
2. User can search the document by providing **a part** of 'IMEI'. Ok, it is solvable too, just wrap the user string to prefix or wildcard query and do the search.
3. And now I need to highlight only those part of 'IMEI', which corresponds to the request, entered by user. And here I stucked.
   If the document.IMEI = 123456789054321, and user entered 2345, Lucene always highlights the whole token: **123456789054321**, but what I need is 1**2345**6789054321.

Is it possible to achieve this, and if yes - how?

PS: here is the code snippet:

```
    String imei = "1234567890";
    KeywordAnalyzer analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
    Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("IMEI", "*2345*"));
    QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);
    Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleSpanFragmenter(scorer);
    Formatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<b>", "</b>");
    Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(formatter, scorer);
    System.out.println(highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, "IMEI", imei));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by writing my own implementation of Formatter.

Comment: Can you please share?